# Редирект при изменении название категории

Tags: .htaccess, редирект, mod-rewrite

Есть url:

```
domain.ru/old-category/old-category/old-category/old-category/old-category/
```

Как делать редирект на:

```
domain.ru/old-category/old-category/new-category/old-category/old-category/
```

То есть, изменить название одной категории по середине.

Comment: может поделитесь с нами, что за технологии вы используете что ли?

Comment: Я не совсем понял что вы имеете ввиду. Редирект через .htaccess

Comment: дак вот именно об этом и речь. метки подправил. приведите более жизненный пример, вряд ли ведь это фактически url  у вас приведены и все 5 секций одинаковые?